# Python pycurl with Twitter Streaming API

Tags: python, api, twitter, streaming, pycurl

I'm using pycurl to crawl data from the Twitter Streaming API. However, after several hours, the connection just hangs there.

Is there anyway to detect this and exit the program? I know pycurl has TIMEOUT and CONNECTTIMEOUT, but these two params do not apply.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an exception or something and could you please add some code? :)
Maybe you should think about using another module like httplib (if you want to
use SSL/TLS you could create a new socket and overwrite the connect function of httplib with
your secure wrapped socket :) )

Comment: Hi Kai,

I use the following code I found through Google.
[link]http://arstechnica.com/open-source/guides/2010/04/tutorial-use-twitters-new-real-time-stream-api-in-python.ars
It's the first code snippet.
I don't get any exception, it just hangs there.
Could you point me to some reliable network library that is easy to use?

Thank you very much,
CJ

Sorry about my formatting. It's so hard to use this editbox.